# Text Component Inside a Form Input

Tags: react-native, tcomb-form-native

My goal is to have a a  component inside a input. These are my options that I am passing to the form from `import t from 'tcomb-form-native';`

```
commentFormOptions = {
  fields: {
    comment: {
      label: 'What do you think?',
      placeholder: 'Type your reply',
      stylesheet: InputStylesheet,
      returnKeyType: 'done',
      onSubmitEditing: () => {
        this.postComment();
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Here you can see where the view is:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    style={styles.commentForm}
    <Form
      ref={ref => this.form = ref}
      type={CommentModel}
      options={this.commentFormOptions} />
  />
    <TouchableHighlight>
      <Text style={{ padding: 10, fontSize: 42 }}>Post</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

I'm not sure I entirely understand why I cant go inside the  and pass in the TouchableHighlight, and Text inside

What am I missing and how can I do this?

#### Edit

You can see here: https://snack.expo.io/HJrXcUtaM but Im trying to get that Post text on the right side of the input, so I can have a onPress to submit it. However; I cannot get the text in the input for some reason.

Comment: What's the error? Why do you have a `<Form>` within your `KeyboardAvoidingView` props declaration? Should it be a child of `KeyboardAvoidingView` instead? Do you want the `TouchableHighlight` to appear below the `Form`?

Comment: There is no error. I just cant see the word Post when I wrap it. Right now  my goal is to get the word Post that I can add a click handler too inside the comment.

Comment: I think you didn't paste the correct code. This wouldn't compile.

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on https://snack.expo.io/?

Comment: @riwu sure - Im waiting for the this to let me run it but it looks something like this: https://snack.expo.io/HJrXcUtaM

Comment: I do see `Post` in your snack example: https://i.imgur.com/SgPw3d9.jpg

Comment: The goal is to put it inside the input. That's the issue like this: https://i.imgur.com/Rs8Hu6h.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to override the default `Textbox` component with your custom `Comment` component. See https://snack.expo.io/ByA_EdYTG.

If you need the `Post` button to be wrapped within the `TextInput` border, You need to create and style your own `TextInput` (put border around the whole container containing the `TextInput` and `TouchableHighlight`).

```
const { Form, Textbox } = t.form;

const Comment = props => (
  <View
    style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}>
    <Textbox {...props} />
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.postButton} onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Text style={{ padding: 10, fontSize: 20 }}>Post</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);

export default class App extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Comments',
  };

  commentFormOptions = {
    fields: {
      comment: {
        label: 'What do you think?',
        placeholder: 'Type your reply',
        returnKeyType: 'done',
        factory: props => (
          <Comment {...props} onPress={() => console.log('pressed')} />
        ),
        stylesheet: {
          ...Form.stylesheet,
          textbox: {
            ...Form.stylesheet.textbox,
            normal: {
              ...Form.stylesheet.textbox.normal,
              width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 70,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```